# How to proxy multiple node apps on the same SSL domain with nginx

Tags: nginx

I've setup few node apps (RESTful servers) on different ports (http://localhost:1337, http://localhost:1338 etc). Each api must be reachable from the same domain and the 443 port.
How would you configure nginx for this specific case?

Here is my nginx configuration

```
# HTTP server

http {

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

# HTTPS server

server {

    listen       443;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/x.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/x.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location /api1 {

            rewrite /api1(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337/;

    }

    location /api2 {

              rewrite /api2(.*)$ $1 break;
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1338/;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Here is my bugged nginx configuration' and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @ALex_hha thx for looking at this issue, I get 502 bad gateway as a response from nginx, here is the answer I get from the client: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/api2/auth/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.` But I don't think this is a CORS related issue.

Comment: .. and this is the nginx error log: `[error] 24043#0: *291 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 79.2.198.102, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /api2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:1338/", host: "www.example.com"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found that the issue wasn't caused by a bad nginx configuration, so the above code should work, even if I made some modifications based on [this snippet found on Github](https://gist.github.com/apollolm/23cdf72bd7db523b4e1c)